# MKMapKit hide Apple maps

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay, apple-maps

Need some help with apple MapKit.
I'm using OSM maps with Tile Overlay and it working really good.
But there is a little problem that I want to fix. I want hide apple maps, because they rendering under the OSM map and when OSM map is loading, Apple maps are visible and that looks strange.

Also device is rendering two maps that is not good...you know.

In guide, that I used to add OSM maps was this code:

```
if ( [map.subviews count] && [((UIView *)[map.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews count] )
    ((UIView *)[((UIView *)[map.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews objectAtIndex:0]).alpha = 0;
```

First of all, this code isn't working for me. And anyway setting alpha to nil is not equal to not rendering. But if there is not way to stop render Apple maps, I can use alpha.

So need some help with this stuff, need to hide apple map.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Update:

I tried to log MKMapKit structure.
Here it is:

```
- MKMapView
- - UIView
- - - MKBasicMapView
- - - - _MKMapLayerHostingView
- - - MKScrollContainerView
- - - - MKOverlayContainerView
- - - MKNewAnnotationContainerView
- - MKAttributionLabel
```

Then I tried this thing:

```
UIView * ll = [[[[[[map subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] subviews] objectAtIndex: 0];
[ll removeFromSuperview];
```

It worked but it hides map with overlays. No idea how to hide map only...
As we see there are layers for overlays, why the hell...oh...any help please. =(

Comment: Why are you using OSM in the first place instead of MapKit alone? And why do you need MapKit if you use OSM ?

Comment: Do you have a link to this "guide" that has that code?  It's generally a _really bad idea_ to rely on an internal, undocumented view hierarchy (especially with MKMapView).

Comment: 2Anna: I agree with you but I need to do it =( I not wany to change mapkit to something else...it's too painfull.

Comment: 2Thomas: Because I not want to write own mapkit or use 3rd party mapkit.

Comment: @KaronatoR, Writing "2xyz" doesn't notify user xyz -- write "@xyz" instead.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 7 and above, you might look at http://mapbox.com/mbxmapkit. But regardless, you shouldn't mess with the `MKMapView` subview hierarchy.